# For-loop-condition (vector of ints). How to get the previous value?

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop, if-statement, stdvector

I have  vector of integers which is filled only by `1` or `0` values. What I am trying to make is that when the **current** value is **1** and **previous/old** is **0** or opposite if `Current=0` and `Previous=1`, then to assign another variable(`AvgCan`) to `0`.

I am trying to get from FOR condition previous value. However, if I try it the usual way I still get the same value all the time until the loop end. The issue is in the first if-statement.

```
int AvgCan = 0;
int OldAvgCan = 0;
int iteration = 0;
int iterationDecrease = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < resultINT.size(); i++)
{
  //myFileO << to_string(resultINT.at(i)) + "\n";
  cout << to_string((resultINT.at(i))) + " Current" + "\n";
  cout << to_string((resultINT.at(i - iteration))) + " Old" + "\n" << endl;
  cout << to_string(AvgCan) + "\n" << endl;

  iteration = i;
  iterationDecrease = i - 1;
  if ((resultINT.at(i)) != (resultINT.at(iteration - iterationDecrease)))
  {
     AvgCan = 0;
  }

  if ((resultINT.at(i)) == 1)
  {
     /*if ((resultINT.at(i- iteration)) != 1)
      {
          AvgCan = 0;
      }*/
     AvgCan++;
  }

  if ((resultINT.at(i)) == 0)
  {
     /*if ((resultINT.at(i- iteration))!=0 )
     {
         AvgCan = 0;
     }*/
     AvgCan--;
  }
  myFileO << to_string(AvgCan) + "\n";
}
```

As you can see I assigned iterator `i` to `iteration` variable and `i - 1` to `iterationDecrease`. (I also tried `i--` and similar possible ways.)

I simulated the data so the results are `1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0`. When it is changing from `1` to `0` and it gets to the if condition, but each next iteration it still returns `1` like *old values*, even when it's `0`.

[image]

I am adding also screenshot for better understanding. On the right side is output in the console.

Comment: change `if ((resultINT.at(i)) != (resultINT.at(iteration - iterationDecrease)))` to `if (resultINT.at(iteration) != resultINT.at(iterationDecrease))`

Comment: You will also have a problem (once the above correction has been made) in that your loop will throw an exception on its first iteration - because you will be calling `.at(-1)`. You need to put in a 'trap' for the first run through the loop.

Comment: What is your desired output? There may be much simpler ways of achieving what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

```
iteration = i;
iterationDecrease = i - 1;

if ((resultINT.at(i)) != (resultINT.at(iteration - iterationDecrease)))
```

the     `iteration - iterationDecrease` is equal to `i - (i - 1)` which is always `1`. Meaning in effect that `if` the statement is equivalent to

```
if ((resultINT.at(i)) != (resultINT.at(1)))
```

You probably meant

```
if (resultINT.at(iteration) != resultINT.at(iterationDecrease))
```

which is still not correct, as when `i==0`, the `iterationDecrease = -1` which will throw an exception, for the call `.at(-1)`

You need to start from `i=1` in the loop therefore,

```
for (int i = 1; i < resultINT.size(); i++)
{
   // ...code
   if (resultINT[i] != resultINT[i-1])
   {
       // ...code
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Think about the expression `iteration - iterationDecrease`. It has a constant value 1.

You wished probably `resultINT.at(iterationDecrease)`, but it will cause an exception on the first iteration, since it will try to access -1 element.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid indexing when it is possible. It is not final solution but it may show you right direction. Use [adjacent_find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) to find pairs. I made this example for you [here](https://onlinegdb.com/HyxzzonWP).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec{ 0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1 };
    auto it = std::begin(vec);
    while (1) {
        it = std::adjacent_find(it, std::end(vec), [](int v1, int v2) { 
            return std::min(v1, v2) == 0 && std::max(v1, v2) == 1; 
        });
        if (it != std::end(vec)) {
            std::cout << "Pairs " << *it << " and " << *(it + 1) << " with indexes "
                << std::distance(std::begin(vec), it) << " and "
                << std::distance(std::begin(vec), it + 1) << std::endl;
            ++it;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

Output
Pairs 0 and 1 with indexes 1 and 2
Pairs 1 and 0 with indexes 3 and 4
Pairs 0 and 1 with indexes 6 and 7
Pairs 1 and 0 with indexes 7 and 8
Pairs 0 and 1 with indexes 8 and 9
Pairs 1 and 0 with indexes 9 and 10
Pairs 0 and 1 with indexes 13 and 14
```